# Multiple columna latex

Tags: latex

Eh estado buscando como se puede hacer lo mismo que en la documentación, eso de poner de un lado la definicion y del otro la explicacion pero no eh visto alguna forma Auxilio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Finalmente lo encontré!

Puedes usar el comando `\marginpar{}` (no requiere ningún paquete) exactamente en la línea de texto que deseas. Además, solo si lo desea, puede usar

```latex
\usepackage[includeall]{geometry}
```

o las opciones apropiadas de [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) para mejorar el layout.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[includeall]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
\textbackslash\texttt{cmdname}\marginpar{\textbackslash\texttt{cmdname}} consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Este código produce este layout:

[image: screenshot of output]

También preste atención a las opciones `oneside`/`twoside` para tener las notas a la izquierda o derecha.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Comment: Gracias, la verdad ya hasta me había dado por vencido, en serio eres un dios del latex

Comment: @DiegoJesusHernandezGonzalez muy bien!!! :)